# Injective homomorphism

Tags: ring-theory

Are there any injective multiplicative homomophisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{F}[x]$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is a field of Characteristic $p$?

Comment: There is always exactly one homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to R$ for any ring $R$. 
The characteristic of a ring can be defined via this unique homomorphism. 
Using these remarks it should be clear what the correct answers are.

Comment: @Curufin: Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @Curufin: I think you have assumed that $R$ is unital and the homomorphism is onto. With these assumptions you are right. But without them, one can construct several homomorphisms. For instance from $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ there are at least three different homomorphisms.

Comment: @Vahid: Why do we need surjectivity as well as $1$? If somewhere in your definition of ring homomorphisms you require that they preserve multiplicative identities, then for any given (unital) ring $R$ there can be only one ring homomorphism $f: \mathbb{Z} \to R$ (since $f(n)$ is determined by $f(1)$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: @CliveNewstead: You misinterpreted my statement a little. First, assuming surjectivity and $R$ being unital implies that the image of $1$ is the unit element of $R$ (in other words, the homomorphism preserves units). Secondly, you can assume the homomorphism is unital (preserves units) and drop the surjectivity assumption.

Comment: @Vahid: I must still be misinterpreting you; what are the ring homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ other than the one determined by $f(1) = (1,1)$? (I'm presuming the ring structure on $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is defined pointwise.)

Comment: Consider for example the homomorphism defined by $n\mapsto (n,0)$ for all integer $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intended ring homomorphisms, then I second Curufin's comment.  But I assumed that, since you wrote "multiplicative", you intend your homomorphisms to *just* preserve multiplication, not necessarily addition.  In that case, such homomorphisms would exist as long as the characteristic of $\mathbb F$ is not 2.  You can define a homomorphism by sending each prime number $q$ to an arbitrarily chosen polynomial $f_q(x)$ in $\mathbb F[x]$ and then extending the map to all integers using the prime factorization: send $\pm q_1^{k_1}\dots q_r^{k_r}$ to $\pm f_{q_1}(x)^{k_1}\dots f_{q_r}(x)^{k_r}$.  To make this homomorphism injective, choose the $f_q$'s a little carefully; for example, choose distinct, irreducible polynomials for distinct primes $q$.

Comment: This looks very close to what I may want. Are there any such things such as "near multiplicative homomorphisms"?

Comment: Ah, I see what he meant. In fancy language: We're looking for injective semi-group homomorphisms from $(\mathbb{Z},\cdot)$ to $(\mathbb{F}[x], \cdot)$.
In fact it seems that every injective semi-group-homomorphism maps prime numbers to polynomials that are relativly prime to every other image of a prime number.

Comment: Are thee any other non-trivial homomorphisms?

Comment: Any multiplicative homomorphism is determined by where it sends the primes and where it sends $-1$, because every integer is a product of these. The examples in my answer (before I specialized to the injective case) are the ones that send $-1$ to $-1$. There are similar ones sending $-1$ to $1$; just delete the $\pm$ from the output (but not the input) in my examples. The only other option is to send $-1$ to $0$ but then, by multiplicativity, everything has to map to $0$

Comment: "Any multiplicative homomorphism is determined by where it sends the primes" Is there a proof for this? I mean would all multiplicative homomorphisms have to arise by fixing primes to polynomials?